# Dynamically Alter a Django Widget's HTML Attributes

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a Django form here that contains a text-input widget. I'd like to be able to change the text-input's HTML value attribute to reflect a user's last search (so they could quickly alter a mistyped query). Now, the snippet bellow doesn't work because `{{ search_form_value }}` gets rendered in the HTML literally. I was thinking I could re-render the HTML, filling out `{{ search_form_value }}`. However, I'm not sure if that could somehow open me up to security related issues (maybe XSS?), or anything else that's not desirable.

If there's an idiomatic/better way to do what I wan't, I'm all ears.

```
class SearchForm (forms.Form) :
    _search_attrs = {'class'       : 'some_css_class',
                     'title'       : 'a title',
                     'placeholder' : 'a placeholder',
                     'value'       : '{{ search_form_value }}'}

    search = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='',
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=_search_attrs))
```

When all's said and done, I'd like the HTML that the client sees to look something like this :

`<input class="some_css_class" maxlength="100" placeholder="a placeholder" title="a title" type="text" value="the users last search">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about saving the last search in [session data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/), then adding the value using the [initial parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) when you initialize the form?

So you view would be something like -

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # process form
        request.session['last_search'] = request.POST['search']
        return HttpResponse()
    else:
        form = SearchForm(initial={'search': request.session.get('last_search')
    return render(request, 'search_page.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply get that, the value must be:

```
'value'       : '{{ request.GET.search }}'}
```

which result to:

```
 <input class="some_css_class" maxlength="100" placeholder="a placeholder" 
     title="a title" type="text" name="search" id="id_search" 
     value="{{ request.GET.search }}">
```